# Why have I just received another two Marshal badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Why have I just now received another two Marshal badges?  I got my first a few months ago.  Surely you should only ever get it the once.

[image: Recent achievements]

Comment: It is another glitch. I got them too.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#280028

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We just did a major revamp of how badges are awarded behind the scenes to drastically reduce the load on SQL Server. It now takes advantage of some pre-compute work we're doing to track badge progress in the profile.
>
> However, I screwed up 2 queries, specifically the text names of the badges that prevent duplicate awarding. I was thinking to myself earlier "hey, maybe we should pass these in" as part of the rewrite - but it's not quite so simple. I'll take another look at this soon but when we're not fighting fires from a SQL Server upgrade. The cardinality changes which hosed some of the bigger badge queries needed urgent attention here, which ended up as a major revamp and introduced the 2 errors reported here.

-- [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/155160)