# My badge count is probably wrong (too many gold)

Tags: bug, status-completed

I know it can sound like a stupid question but it seems that my badges count is wrong. I remember having 11 gold and today the total is 13. I've checked the badge page and counted them and... still 11.

As it can be a bug affecting other users, I prefer to ask/report it. Especially if there's something to fix on AU.

Comment: They are running a lot of queries over the DB recently I remember having 3 marshal badges a few days ago. which now is corrected again.

Comment: #firstworldproblems :p

Comment: I love this kind of bugs actually :)

Comment: Related? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15537/why-have-i-just-received-another-two-marshal-badges?

Comment: This will get cleaned up - we have a cleanup script that runs on 3am UTC - will be corrected after that. It was caused by the issue @muru linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the link @muru

Comment: Not fixed so far.

Comment: Now it is fixed.

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm. Thanks @Pilot6